# Google Maps in Pie and Above Version

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using Google maps and also created a new project with google maps activity but google maps not working. i have added key also but it just open the activity no marker or other options work

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
```

Dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Did you see map in your activity?

Comment: yes, that activity is opening. but no map showing in the activity.

Comment: Please put your layout also.

Comment: layout activity code added

Comment: @PuneetKansal Enable Permission in your Google play API console. ENABLE it. Enable permission for Maps and places API

Comment: I have enabled it. but not working

Comment: Are you use `implements OnMapReadyCallback` in your activity class ?

Comment: is your internet connection on?

Comment: Yes,internet is on | Yes i using implements OnMapReadyCallback {

Comment: Anyone Have an Answer. I added layout also in the code.

Comment: ?? @Ankit have you got any answer. you can try to create new project in androidx with google maps activity and you will get result like this

Comment: i tried that it worked for me,may be your api key is not valid try to generate non-restricted new api key

Comment: @Ankit Thanks for the reply. can you please tell me the api name. i am using Maps SDK for Android api

Comment: @Ankit Thanks this time worked with api. I don't know by this was not worked before.

Comment: in developer console inside credentials you have to create API key starts with Alza... and put inside google_maps_api.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean the project and update the api key it will start working.